# How can I modify my Continuous Ping batch to write to a new file daily as a Scheduled Task?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scheduled-tasks, ping

How can I modify the code below to have it write to a new dated file after midnight every day?

```bash
set host="8.8.8.8"
set curdate="%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-2,2%"
set filep="c:\ping\ping-%curdate%.txt"

ping -t %host% | cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data! -)&ping -n 2 %host%>nul">>%filep%
```

If I can get the code to terminate prior to midnight, using some sort of "if time=11:59, then stop script", that should solve my problem. Task Scheduler only has specified values like 12 hours, or 1 day.

(update 5-31-23) I have tested numerous things and posted a work-around as an answer.

Comment: You set `filep` one time - it doesn't change anymore. Redirect to `>> "c:\ping\ping-!date:~-10,2!-!date:~-7,2!-!date:~-2,2!.txt"` instead (using delayed expansion) instead of `>>%filep%`

Comment: I am actually testing it on the old script first, which does not have any variable declaration. Most of that was just to make it easier to modify. I thought this might end up being a problem, so I wanted to make sure it worked without the variables first. Right now, it "does what it's supposed to" using Run instance in parallel option on the last tab, and setting ping to "ping -w 2000 -n 86400 x.x.x.x |" and that is the closest I can get it to work. I am testing now with the variable version to see if it works, won't know until tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't found a time-based termination of the batch (at 11:59pm, terminate), I did manage to do a work-around that will be good enough for me.

I made modifications to the first ping command. Instead of "ping -t" I did "ping -w 2000 -n 86400". This makes it only wait 2 seconds for failure, and ping for 86400 times (1 day's worth of seconds, may get slightly less if it pings well all day, or slightly more if request timed out, but close enough).

Next, the Task Scheduler doesn't seem to properly end the task even with all end/stop task after 1 day things are set. To get around this, along with the "timer" on the ping, on the last tab of task scheduler, the dropdown at the bottom, set it to "Run another instance in parallel". This will always start the script at 12:00:05am even if a batch is running, then the previous day's batch will stop after the pings run out.

```bash
set host="8.8.8.8"
set curdate="%date:~-10,2%-%date:~-7,2%-%date:~-2,2%"
set filep="c:\ping\ping-%curdate%.txt"

ping -w 2000 -n 86400 %host% | cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data! -)&ping -n 2 %host%>nul">>%filep%
```

I will have to test this on other operating systems and other computers to ensure it functions the same across the board, but I believe it will accomplish what I need it to for now. (still interested to know if time-based termination is possible)

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question, spent over an hour last night trying to come up with a solution within the script. I think the issue is that while `cmd /v` enables delayed environment variable expansion, and that allows the date + time you're outputting to file to remain current, that doesn't apply to the filename you're piping the results to, and I can't think of a way around that.

Unfortunatly I suspect the only work around that will do it (unless someone comes up with a better idea) is to use Task Scheduler to handle stopping and restarting the script each day.

Create the task and in Triggers set it to run Daily at `00:00:00`

In Settings, make sure `Allow task to be run on demand` is ticked (so you can manually start it when required), then at the bottom change `Do not start a new instance` to be `Stop the existing instance`.

That combination should mean that you can start the script whenever you want, then at midnight a new instance of the script will be started on schedule which in turn stops the previously running instance. Since it's now a new instance of the script it will pick up the new date, and therefore output the results to a new file with the current date.

If you want you might also be able to use `schtasks` to initiate the task via `cmd` or another script if needed. But I've not used it so can't comment on how well it actually works.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks-run

Comment: Oh wow, you didn't need to spend all that time on it! I will have to try that out, it's not anything urgent, just wanted to avoid the potential of having notepad unable to open the file because it's too large. I had seen several iterations of this batch but none address the ever-changing filename dilemma I'm in. I was wondering if there as a way to do like an "If time = 11:59, then abort script" then at midnight, it will just rerun itself, I'm just not familiar enough with if/then, or this specific code, to try anything. I appreciate your time

Comment: Looks like most of my settings match that. I did see "Run instance in parallel" and I have it set to stop if it runs longer than 1 day, so I will see if this will do what I need it to. It might overlap a little bit, but it might also not correctly terminate the initial instance, so tomorrow I will find out. Would still like it to terminate before if that is at all doable.

Comment: Lol, honestly didn't intend to but lost track of time with the interesting puzzle. Plus some of the elements of your line of code I've not seen someeone use before, so it was fun digging into the "I know WHAT it's doing, and broadly how it works, but how exactly do some of those elements function so I can find a way to tweak them so they work!" :)

Comment: So the run in parallel starts a NEW file, but it keeps the OLD file as well, so it is appending to TWO files at once. However, it did make a new file. I might just change the first "ping -t" to "ping -n 86400 -w 2000" so it'll only wait 2 seconds (vs. 4) and ping for an entire day (86,400 seconds worth), but if I get a bunch of failures, it won't continue to run too long. I think this is the only workaround. I will let it run this weekend and see if it works as I am assuming. It would be cool to figure out how to terminate the batch at a certain time though!

Comment: Yeah that's why I suggested the `Stop the existing instance` setting rather than parallel. So when the 2nd one starts the 1st one stops. I think if you set it to stop after 1 day that might work as you expect after a day has passed, but the first time you pass midnight it'll continue running the first instance until it has been running for 24 hours which will be after midnight if you started it manually.

Comment: I had it set to stop the instance after 1 day, but it was still pinging til 8:30am when I stopped it. I never seem to have success with this stop function in the tasks. Not sure why. I have 2 batches running for the weekend. One parallel with the -w -n modifications above, and one with the original settings and all possible stop options flagged. So we'll see what happens.

Comment: Running in parallel in task scheduler, along with "ping -w 2000 -n 86400 x.x.x.x" as the first command seems to most closely achieve my goal. I have the other batch as it was, and while it does create a named file each day, it still manages to add on to the previous days, causing them to be massive text files, the further you go back. I don't understand why the switches/options in the task scheduler do not successfully terminate the batch, but they don't.